# Redesign the dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns: `item` and `value`. The `value` column have values as list of tuples where the first element is the field and the second element is the count.

```
**item  value**
item1   
item2   
item3   [('f1', 10L), ('f3', 5L)]
item4   [('f4', 2L)]
item5   [('f5', 1L)]
```

I need to expand/redesign the dataframe in the following form.

```
**item  f1  f3  f4  f5**
item1               
item2               
item3   10  5       
item4           2   
item5               1
```

Is there any function in pandas where this can be done quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mixed types of lists and np.nan which is not iterable, you can do a type check, if the value is a list tuples then call *pd.Series* on it after converting it a dictionary, otherwise construct an empty *Series* object:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
lst = [np.nan, np.nan, 
      [('f1', 10), ('f3', 5)], 
      [('f4', 2)], 
      [('f5', 1)]]

df = pd.DataFrame({"item": ["item"+str(i) for i in range(1,6)], "value": let})

pd.concat([df.item, df['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(x)) if type(x) == list else pd.Series([]))], axis = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: OP may need a more generalized solution. There may be more values and items than simple post.

Comment: @Parfait That is likely. I'll wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: True, there are more values. The one in my original post is just a toy example.

Comment: So what are those values? string/numeric/iterable?

Comment: `item` is always string. `value` is either `np.nan` or `list of tuples`.

Comment: @Psidom, edited the OP to make is simple. I made the `value` column simply a list of tuples.

Comment: If you just have two types of data in the `value` column, you can do a type check and then construct series for each value respectively.

Comment: @Psidom, thanks. I  chnaged the value type and initiated with an empty list. This worked for me.

Comment: That would be the best solution if you can control what you have for your `value` column.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this data wrangling that builds up a list of dictionaries by separating for both data and nondata, then concatenating them together with pivot tables. This may more generalizable for any number and combination of `f` types:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'item':['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'],
                   'value':['', '', [('f1', 10), ('f3', 5)], [('f4', 2)], [('f5', 1)]]})

# ACTUAL DATA
data = [{'fcols': i[0], 'value': i[1], 'item': row['item']}
        for ix, row in df.iterrows() if len(row['value']) > 0 for i in row['value']]
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data).pivot_table(index='item', values='value', columns='fcols').reset_index()

# NON-DATA
fcols = [i[0] for f in df['value'].tolist() if len(f) > 0 for i in f]
nondata = [{'value': np.nan, 'item': row['item'], 'fcols':f}
           for ix, row in df.iterrows() if row['value'] == '' for f in fcols]     
nondf = pd.DataFrame(nondata).pivot_table(index='item', values='value', columns='fcols').reset_index()

# COMBINED DF
newdf = pd.concat([nondf,newdf]).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

print(newdf)

#     item    f1   f3   f4   f5
# 0  item1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 1  item2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 2  item3  10.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
# 3  item4   NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
# 4  item5   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
```